# Add a 3nd request in SQL thanks 2 others request

Tags: sql, pivot, average, aggregate-functions

I would like to know how i can calculate the difference between 2 request in SQl

I got my first requete (req1):

```
SELECT AVG( "Salaire" ) FROM "Enseignant" WHERE "Sexe" = 'M'
```

and my second request  (req2) :

```
SELECT AVG( "Salaire" ) FROM "Enseignant" WHERE "Sexe" = 'F'
```

and in my last request I want to do :

```
req2-req1
```

But I got no idea how it can works, I tried too much things ...

thanks !!

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    avg(case when sexe = 'M' then salaire end) avg_salaire_m,
    avg(case when sexe = 'F' then salaire end) avg_salaire_f,
    avg(case when sexe = 'M' then salaire end) - avg(case when sexe = 'F' then salaire end) avg_salaire_diff
from enseignant
```

Answer (score 0):

did you mean it

```
select
   (SELECT AVG( "Salaire" ) FROM "Enseignant" WHERE "Sexe" = 'M')
   -
   (SELECT AVG( "Salaire" ) FROM "Enseignant" WHERE "Sexe" = 'F')
```